# How find numbers in this list of inequalities?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Consider for example `list = {1 < x < 1.8, x > 1.8, x == 1. || x == 1.8}`.

I want to get the (floating) numbers in this list, i.e. `1.` and `1.8`. They can be accessed with `Take`, for example  `list[[1, 3]]` returns `1.8`. So I could iterate over each element of the list, find it's dimensions and select each part and keep only floating numbers. But I suppose there is a simpler way.

The question is, is there a simple function to return `{1.,1.8}` from `list`?

Comment: `Cases[list, _Real, Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cases` would work here.

```
Cases[list, _Real, Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> `{1.8, 1.}`